# Stripe: Plan change after period ends

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, prestashop-1.6

I have several customers subscribed to many other several Stripe plans on my website: These plans are all 'yearly' and have different subscribing amounts. Notice that I also have customers with a subscription status "active" and many others with "trialing".

Now, I need to automatically change their subscription plans to an unique new yearly plan, with a different subscription amount, at the end of their respective billing cycles.

I was looking for the properly event in order to do the change of plan programmatically within a webhook, but I don't know which to choose having both 'active' and 'trialing' subscriptions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `invoice.upcoming` the event will work for both trailing and active. subscription.

you can configure invoice.upcoming webhook to arrive 1 day before and modify customer's subscription and invoice.

> invoice.upcoming : Occurs X number of days before a subscription is
>   scheduled to create an invoice that is charged automatically, where X
>   is determined by your subscriptions settings. Note the received
>   invoice object will not have an invoice ID.

Hope this helps you